# Is there any way to find out whether objective-c class is derived from another perticuliar class

Tags: objective-c, plugins

I want to  create a plug-in system using objective-c. I am getting list of all classes in the main bundle and checking for classes derived from plug-in base.

```
 int count = objc_getClassList(NULL, 0);  
 Class * buffer = (Class *)malloc(sizeof(Class) * count);  
 objc_getClassList(buf, count);

 NSMutableArray * classNameArray = [NSMutableArray array];

 for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) 
 {



  [buf[i] isDerivedFromClass:[PluginBase class]]; //<<< I need this
  NSString * classname=NSStringFromClass(buf[i]);

  [classNameArray  addObject:classname]; 

 }
```

Is there any equivalent method for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you *can* use `isKindOfClass:` to do exactly the kind of checking you describe, are you sure this is what you need? A bundle can declare *any* class as its principle class, and if that class supplies the same methods as your plugin base class then it can be used as such (this is Objective-C's *duck typing*). Therefore you could be testing, rather than for subclasses, for existence of the plugin's API methods.

It also looks like you've missed out on using the principle class. Looking at [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html), a bundle can declare in its `Info.plist` file a class that represents the entry point to that bundle's functionality. Rather than searching through every class looking for something compatible with your API, you can just require that plug-in authors register a compatible principle class. This approach allows plug-in authors to declare multiple conforming classes for using patterns like Strategy, State or Decorator while still exposing a single entry point. Your approach described in your question would try to use all of those instances concurrently.

Comment: OK. Forget about plug-in. I am trying to get list of all classes in the main bundle that is derived from some specific class.  I guess isKindOfClass works only if the receiver is a object and not plain CLASS.

Comment: @shakthi: you can use `[MyClass isSubclassOfClass: [InterestingClass class]]`

Comment: @ Graham Lee: You should make that comment an answer because it is the correct answer to the question asked.

Comment: @JeremyP: it is, but only because I believe the question being asked is the wrong one :)

Comment: Ok. I changed the approach. I am using protocols now.  `if (class_conformsToProtocol(aClass, @protocol(PluginProtocal)))`. works for me .

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
BOOL b = [yourObject isKindOfClass:[PluginBase class]];
```

You can use `isMemberOfClass:` to get *exact* class match.

**Edit:** For class objects, use the static `(BOOL)isSubclassOfClass:(Class)aClass` method:

```
BOOL b = [yourClassObject isSubclassOfClass:[PluginBase class]];
```

Comment: I guess isKindOfClass works only if the receiver is a object and not plain CLASS.

Comment: Oops, sorry, looked like "normal" objects. Edited the answer with the solution.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the answer. I tried with `if ([aClass isSubclassOfClass:[PluginBase class]])`, But still  it failed with some of classes saying "class 'Object' does not implement doesNotRecognizeSelector: -- abort". I guess thier may be some classes in the list that are not dervied from NSOBject. I go to  Graham Lee soln